# Mysql creating a new column but already exist

Tags: mysql

Here is my table SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kiln_input_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kiln_num` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `chargenum` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `datein` date NOT NULL,
  `dateout` date NOT NULL,
  `drytime` decimal(12,1) NOT NULL,
  `kilnsched` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `target` decimal(12,1) NOT NULL,
  `emc` decimal(12,1) NOT NULL,
  `tdal` decimal(11,1) NOT NULL,
  `opinit` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `mca` decimal(12,1) NOT NULL,
  `stda` decimal(11,1) NOT NULL,
  `mcb` decimal(12,1) NOT NULL,
  `sdtb` decimal(11,1) NOT NULL,
  `checkdimension` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `bf4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bf6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bf8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bf90` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bf105` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `_submitted_` date NOT NULL,
  `_fromaddress_` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

All works fine, however, after inserting data from form I get a repeat column stdb appended to the end of the table, not sure why

```
kiln_input_data

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
id  int(11) No       
kiln_num    decimal(11,0)   Yes     NULL     
chargenum   varchar(20) No       
datein  date    No       
dateout date    No       
drytime decimal(12,1)   Yes     NULL     
kilnsched   decimal(11,0)   Yes     NULL     
target  decimal(12,1)   Yes     NULL     
emc decimal(12,1)   Yes     NULL     
tdal    decimal(12,1)   Yes     NULL     
opinit  varchar(5)  No       
mca decimal(12,1)   Yes     NULL     
stda    decimal(12,1)   Yes     NULL     
mcb decimal(12,1)   Yes     NULL     
sdtb    decimal(11,1)   No       
checkdimension  varchar(20) No       
bf4 decimal(11,0)   Yes     NULL     
bf6 decimal(11,0)   Yes     NULL     
bf8 decimal(11,0)   Yes     NULL     
bf90    decimal(11,0)   Yes     NULL     
bf105   decimal(11,0)   Yes     NULL     
_submitted_ date    No       
_fromaddress_   varchar(20) No       
stdb    decimal(12,1)   Yes     NULL
```

Comment: doing an `insert` on a table can NOT possibly ever create a new field in the table. That requires an `alter` query. Plus, it's not a repeated field. `sdtb` v.s. `stdb`...

Comment: I found out why, I created a table to accept data from coffecup form builder form, but the form when submitted created the table over my table.  Weird right. So I dropped my table, ran the form again and it created its own table.  Solved